Problem on the composition of superconformal transformations
Maybe this is a dumb question. Problem 10.2 of Polchinski's String Theory book: The objective is to prove that the commutator of two infinitesimal superconformal transformations is a conformal one.
Using equations 10.1.10 it is not difficult to get the expresion
\begin{array}{l}
 \epsilon _{1}^{-1} \epsilon _{2}^{-1}\left[ \delta _{\eta _{1}} \delta _{\eta _{2}} - \delta _{\eta _{2}} \delta _{\eta _{1}}\right] X^{\mu }( z,\overline{z}) =-[ -2\eta _{1}( z) \eta _{2}( z)] \partial X^{\mu }( z) -\left[ -2\eta _{1}( z)^{*} \eta _{2}( z)^{*}\right]\overline{\partial } X^{\mu }(\overline{z})
\end{array}
By defining $v(z)= -2\eta _{1}( z)\eta _{2}(z)$ obtain the first term in the conformal transformation for $X^\mu$, but I have problems with the second. Since $\eta_{1,2}$ are anticommuting numbers we get
\begin{array}{l}
 \epsilon _{1}^{-1} \epsilon _{2}^{-1}\left[ \delta _{\eta _{1}} \delta _{\eta _{2}} - \delta _{\eta _{2}} \delta _{\eta _{1}}\right] X^{\mu }( z,\overline{z}) \\=-v( z) \partial X^{\mu }( z) -\left[ -2[\eta _{2}( z)\eta _{1}( z)]^{*}\right]\overline{\partial } X^{\mu }(\overline{z})\\=-v( z) \partial X^{\mu }( z)+\left[-2\eta _{1}( z)\eta _{2}( z)\right]^{*}\overline{\partial } X^{\mu }(\overline{z})\\=-v( z) \partial X^{\mu }( z)+v(z)^{*}\overline{\partial } X^{\mu }(\overline{z})
\end{array}
and the second term has the opposite sign. What could be wrong?
